# Magento 2 EE: Running composer update is giving error

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, composer, docker, magento-cloud

I am trying to run composer update and want to push the changes to magento cloud but is giving the following error:

Problem 1

- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.4 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.4 requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.
- Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.3.4 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.3.4].

Maybe because it is conflicting with my local PHP environment?
I am running the command outside the docker container. Is it necessary to run the commands inside a docker container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Composer must be run using PHP that is used by your Magento instance. If you use a Docker setup, you need to run it inside Docker container (via 'docker exec' command, see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

Answer (score 0):

run

```
sudo apt install php7.x-bcmath
```

change `x` with your PHP version